# Looping EditText addTextchangedListener

Tags: android

I'm trying to initialize my addTextchangedListener via loop. In my app, the user will have to input the From(%) value and the To(%) will be created programmatically.

```
+-------------+-------+--------+
| Equivalents | To(%) | From(%)|
+-------------+-------+--------+
|   1.00      | 100   |  99    |
--------------------------------
|   1.25      | 98    |  95    |
```

Here's my code:

```
to[0].setText("100");

 for(j=0;j<8;j++){
                         from[j].addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
                                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                                    String checkrf= (from[j].getText().toString());
                                    if(checkrf.equals("")){
                                        j=j+1;
                                         to[j].setText("");
                                    }
                                    else{
                                    int rt = Integer.parseInt( to[j].getText().toString() );    

                                    int rf = Integer.parseInt( from[j].getText().toString() );
                                    if(rt>rf){ 
                                    rf= rf-1;
                                     j=j+1;
                                     to[j].setText(""+rf);
                                    }

                                    else{
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"From(%) should is Smaller than To(%)",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        from[j].setText("");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
                                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}

                                }); 
                }
```

However, my code does nothing. I tried to implement it without using loop and it worked well. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what you want to create actually? that above table pattern?

Comment: I'm trying to create it on my interface. But not on my database table.